# Sql query for a self-referencing table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table (ms sql 2008) where i store user replacements. It is in the form:

```
| ID| U1| U2|

| 1 | A | B |

| 2 | B | C |

| 3 | C | D |
```

User A was replaced by user B. Then B was replaced by C and then C was replaced by D. Replacements may be 1-n.

How can i have the (logical) result in one row that right now A is replaced by D?

```
| A | D |
```

Comment: Build a table of ultimate replacements. That will mean you don't have to write the query, you can do just one lookup and it will be much faster.

Comment: what should happen if you have row with values D, A also? could you clarify your input and output? do you have 2 user ids as input?

Comment: Yes, it is possible user D to be replaced by user A and yes, i have 2 user ids.

Comment: so could you clarify what do you put as input and how do you want to get your output. Is it "here's user1, here's user2, is user1 could be replaced by user2"?

Comment: I think it's clear. I have the table you see in code 1 and the output, from a stored procedure, should be code 2.

Comment: In the case of A->B->C->D->A... How is the last replacement identified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [recursive CTE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) you can find the final replacement for each row.

```
WITH RCTE AS
(
    SELECT ID, U1, U2, 1 AS Lvl 
    FROM dbo.table1 --WHERE ID = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT r.ID, r.U1, t1.U2, r.Lvl + 1 
    FROM dbo.table1 t1
    INNER JOIN RCTE r ON r.U2 = t1.U1 AND t1.ID > r.ID
)
, CTE_RN AS 
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Lvl DESC) RN 
    FROM RCTE
)
SELECT ID, u1, U2 AS FinalReplacement
FROM CTE_RN c
WHERE RN = 1 
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.table1 t1 WHERE c.u1 = t1.U2)
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5c3b6/1)**

Comment: I just tried it, Nenad, and there is an infinite loop in case user D is replaced by A.

Comment: @ConstantinosG. Assuming that the ID in your table reflects the order of the replacements you can change ´ON r.U2 = t1.U1´ to ´ON r.U2 = t1.U1 AND r.ID>t1.ID´.

Comment: @Taemyr: ID indeed reflects the order but your proposition gives wrong results.

Comment: @ConstantinosG. Please update sample data and expected results in your question for additional requirements. If user D is replaced by A -  of-course you are going to have infinite loop. What would be your desired output in that case?

Comment: @Nenad: in case D is replaced by A, the ouput should be empty (no rows).

Comment: @ConstantinosG.. Suggestion by @Taemyr was correct except the operation was inverted. Adding `AND t1.ID > r.ID` to JOIN criteria in recursive part of CTE will do. Answer edited. Unfortunately SQLFiddle seems to be down at the moment, I can't edit demo.

Comment: @Nenad: you are right. And to handle dublicate replacements (since we can not use distinct in CTE) like A replaced again by B (2nd time), the join should be 'ON r.U2 = t1.U1 AND t1.ID > r.ID AND (t1.U1 <> r.U1 AND t1.U2 <> r.U2)'. Please update your answer if you agree and I will mark it as accepted.